# OpenGL to eliminate tiles from the mesh as in the game candy crush?

Tags: opengl

*This code will generate a mesh.
It will switch the colors of the 2 adjacent tiles which are selected using mouse one after the another.
As a result, same color tiles may be present next to each other.
I want to eleminate such tiles out of the mesh*

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<glut.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define maxx 11
#define maxy 11
#define dx 50
#define dy 50

typedef struct cell
{
    GLfloat x0,y0,x1,y1;
    int color;
}cellt;

cellt board[20][20];
GLfloat color[3][3]={{0,0,1},{0,1,0},{1,0,0}};
GLfloat x0=0,y0=0;
GLint i,j,stroke=0,pastx,pasty,nextx,nexty,swapthetwo=0;

void init()
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glPointSize(5.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,499.0,0.0,499.0);
    glutPostRedisplay();
    for(i=0;i<maxx;i++)
        for(j=0;j<maxy;j++)
        {
            board[i][j].x0=x0+i*dx+1;
            board[i][j].x1=x0+(i+1)*dx-1;
            board[i][j].y0=y0+j*dy+1;
            board[i][j].y1=y0+(j+1)*dy-1;
            board[i][j].color=rand()%3;
        }
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    for(i=0;i<maxx-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<maxy-1;j++)
        {
             glColor3fv(color[board[i][j].color]);
             glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
               glVertex2f(board[i][j].x0,board[i][j].y0);
               glVertex2f(board[i][j].x0,board[i][j].y1);
               glVertex2f(board[i][j].x1,board[i][j].y1);
               glVertex2f(board[i][j].x1,board[i][j].y0);
             glEnd();
             glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
             glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
               glVertex2f(board[i][j].x0,board[i][j].y0);
               glVertex2f(board[i][j].x0,board[i][j].y1);
               glVertex2f(board[i][j].x1,board[i][j].y1);
               glVertex2f(board[i][j].x1,board[i][j].y0);
             glEnd();
        }
    }
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void mouse(int btn,int status,int x,int y) //mouse interfacing
{
    y=500-y;
    if((stroke == 0) && (btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) && (status == GLUT_DOWN))
    {
        stroke=1;
        pastx=x;
        pasty=y;
        printf("pastx=%d,%d\n",pastx/dx,pasty/dy);
    }
    if((stroke == 1) && (btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) && (status == GLUT_UP))
    {
        stroke=0;
        nextx=x;
        nexty=y;
        printf("nextx=%d,%d\n",nextx/dx,nexty/dy);
        if(abs(((pastx/dx)-(nextx/dx)) == 1) && ((pasty/dy) == (nexty/dy)))
            swapthetwo=1;
        if(abs(((pasty/dy)-(nexty/dy)) == 1) && ((pastx/dx) == (nextx/dx)))
            swapthetwo=1;
    }
}

void idle(void)
{
    int temp;
    if(swapthetwo)
    {
         swapthetwo=0;
         temp=board[pastx/dx][pasty/dy].color;
         board[pastx/dx][pasty/dy].color=board[nextx/dx][nexty/dy].color;
         board[nextx/dx][nexty/dy].color=temp;
         printf("swapped");
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)  
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutCreateWindow("mesh");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Yuo should post your code first and together well try to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting another question(regarding the same project) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36218896/how-do-i-allocate-colors-to-tiles-in-a-game-like-candy-crush) which is more relevant.
By fluke i saw my code in this question which you might have taken from my blog.
You may want to update your question after my answer. The question you are asking is about is in the following code:

```
if(abs(((pastx/dx)-(nextx/dx)) == 1) && ((pasty/dy) == (nexty/dy)))
            swapthetwo=1;
if(abs(((pasty/dy)-(nexty/dy)) == 1) && ((pastx/dx) == (nextx/dx)))
            swapthetwo=1;
```

Which is inside the mouse function. Before setting swapthetwo run a loop to check if that row or column are having same colored tiles. You should loop two tiles on all the four directions. If any color are same swap, vanish and move down. Otherwise flip back.
I have defined four functions to vanish the tiles like this:

```
void vanishup(int i,int j)
{
    board[i][j].color=4;
    board[i][j+1].color=4;
    board[i][j+2].color=4;

whitecount+=3;
}
void vanishleft(int i,int j)
{
    board[i][j].color=4;
    board[i-1][j].color=4;
    board[i-2][j].color=4;
    whitecount+=3;
}
void vanishdown(int i,int j)
{

    board[i][j].color=4;
    board[i][j-1].color=4;
    board[i][j-2].color=4;
    whitecount+=3;

}
void vanishright(int i,int j)
{

    board[i][j].color=4;
    board[i+1][j].color=4;
    board[i+2][j].color=4;
    whitecount+=3;
}
```

Then in the display function calling these vanish functions when the conditions are right:

```
//detecting three colors in a row
    if(!whitecount)
    {
        for(i=0;i<maxx-1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<maxy-1;j++)
            {
                flag=0;
                col=10;
                for(k=0;k<3;k++)
                {
                    if(k==0)
                        if(((j+k)<maxy-1))
                            col=board[i][j+k].color;
                if(((j+k)<maxy-1))
                {   if(board[i][j+k].color!=col)
                    {flag=1;
                break;}
                }
                else flag=1;
                }
                if(!flag&&!vanishing)
                    vanishup(i,j);
                    //printf("vanish up\n");
                flag=0;
                col=10;
                for(k=0;k<3;k++)
                {
                    if(k==0)
                        if((j-k)>=0)
                        col=board[i][j-k].color;
                if(((j-k)>=0))
                {   if(board[i][j-k].color!=col)
                    {flag=1;
                break;}
                }
                else flag=1;
                }
                if(!flag&&!vanishing)
                    vanishdown(i,j);
                    //printf("vanish down\n");
                flag=0;
                col=10;
                for(k=0;k<3;k++)
                {
                    if(k==0)
                        if(((i+k)<maxx-1))
                            col=board[i+k][j].color;
                if(((i+k)<maxx-1))
                {   if(board[i+k][j].color!=col)
                    {flag=1;
                break;}
                }
                else flag=1;
                }
                if(!flag&&!vanishing)
                    vanishright(i,j);
                    //printf("vanish right\n");
                flag=0;
                col=10;
                for(k=0;k<3;k++)
                {
                    if(k==0)
                        if(((i-k)>=0)) col=board[i-k][j].color;
                if(((i-k)>=0))
                {   if(board[i-k][j].color!=col)
                    {flag=1;
                break;}
                } else flag=1;
                }
                if(!flag&&!vanishing)
                    vanishleft(i,j);
                    //printf("vanish left\n");

            }
        }
    }
```

Finally move all those blocks down which have a white block above them:

```
//move all blocks down if white spaces exist(some blocks vanished)

flag1=0;
    for(i=0;i<maxx-1;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<maxy-1;j++)
                {

                    if(board[i][j].color==4) //if any board color white
                    {
                    if((j+1)<(maxy-1))      // if any board position not above board
                    {   board[i][j].color=board[i][j+1].color;//move above color

                    board[i][j+1].color=4;                     // to below

                    }
                    else
                        {board[i][j].color=4;
                        whitecount--;
                        }
                    }
                    //else movecount--;

                }

            }
    if(flag1) movecount=0;
    cout<<movecount<<" "<<whitecount<<" ";
```

I must agree after taking all the pains still i am not satisfied as there are several bugs. 
1) While the blocks are moving down if any three colours form a line even temporarily they vanish. 
2) Another problem is two different coloured lines vanish at the same time.