# How do i allocate colors to tiles in a game like candy crush

Tags: c++, c, opengl, stl

I have worked on a partial game in C/C++ where the tiles get exchanged [Here](http://cglabprojects.blogspot.com/2015/02/tiles-exchange-like-candy-crush.html).
I want to now implement candy crush and i know drawing the candies will take lot of effort. Just let the tiles do the job.
In the part on assigning colours to tiles i don't want three colours to appear in a row or column. How do i do this in an efficient way.
I am presently allotting colours randomly like this:

```
board[i][j].color=rand()%3;
```

Which looks like this:
[image: Snapshot of program]

Yes I don't want three cells or tiles in a row or column to have same colour that is no more than two adjacent tiles of same colour.
 I mean i don't want a solution where colours are allotted once and a check made if three tiles in a line have same colours. If not generate colours for all the tiles again. That would be too naive and costly.
Another solution may be before assigning a colour to a tile in raster order checking to see if two tiles below or to the left have same colour if so allot some other colour. That too is obvious. Is there a better way?

Subsequent to Weather Wane's answer I am posting code that is doing the set difference operation using STL iterators and set_difference method. What i am trying is before choosing randomly from a set of colors i am forming that set by eliminating only those colors which are already repeated twice(below or left) using set operation. There is something wrong in the code. I don't have much knowledge of STL. Can anyone please guide how i can use it properly.

```
for(j=0;j<maxy;j++)
{for(i=0;i<maxx;i++)
{
    int first[] = {0,1,2,3},fsize,i34;
    std::vector<int> v(5);                     
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;

    board[i][j].x0=x0+i*dx+1;
    board[i][j].x1=x0+(i+1)*dx-1;
    board[i][j].y0=y0+j*dy+1;
    board[i][j].y1=y0+(j+1)*dy-1;


    if((i-1)>=0&&board[i-1][j].color==0&&(i-2)>=0&&board[i-2][j].color==0)
    {int second[] = {0};
    std::sort (first,first+4);     
    it=std::set_difference (first, first+4, second, second+1, v.begin());
    v.resize(it-v.begin());                      
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), first);
    }
    fsize=v.size();
    if((i-1)>=0&&board[i-1][j].color==1&&(i-2)>=0&&board[i-2][j].color==1)
    {int second[] = {1};
    std::sort (first,first+fsize);     //  5 10 15 20 25
    it=std::set_difference (first, first+fsize, second, second+1, v.begin());
                                            //  5 15 25  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    v.resize(it-v.begin());                      //  5 15 25
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), first);
    }
    fsize=v.size();
    if((i-1)>=0&&board[i-1][j].color==2&&(i-2)>=0&&board[i-2][j].color==2)
    {int second[] = {2};
    std::sort (first,first+fsize);     //  5 10 15 20 25
    it=std::set_difference (first, first+fsize, second, second+1, v.begin());
                                       //  5 15 25  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    v.resize(it-v.begin());                      //  5 15 25
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), first);
    }
    fsize=v.size();
    if((j-1)>=0&&board[i][j-1].color==0&&(j-2)>=0&&board[i][j-2].color==0)
    {int second[] = {0};
    std::sort (first,first+fsize);     //  5 10 15 20 25
    it=std::set_difference (first, first+fsize, second, second+1, v.begin());
                                       //  5 15 25  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    v.resize(it-v.begin());                      //  5 15 25
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), first);
    }
    fsize=v.size();
    if((j-1)>=0&&board[i][j-1].color==1&&(j-2)>=0&&board[i][j-2].color==1)
    {int second[] = {1};
    std::sort (first,first+fsize);     //  5 10 15 20 25
    it=std::set_difference (first, first+fsize, second, second+1, v.begin());
                              //  5 15 25  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    v.resize(it-v.begin());                      //  5 15 25
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), first);
    }
    fsize=v.size();
    if((j-1)>=0&&board[i][j-1].color==2&&(j-2)>=0&&board[i][j-2].color==2)
    {int second[] = {2};
    std::sort (first,first+fsize);     //  5 10 15 20 25
                                    // 10 20 30 40 50
    it=std::set_difference (first, first+fsize, second, second+1, v.begin());
                                  //  5 15 25  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    v.resize(it-v.begin());                      //  5 15 25
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), first);
    }
    //  first=&v[0];
    fsize=v.size();
    cout<<v.size()<<" ";
    for(i34=0,it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++)
    {cout<<*it<<" "; first[i34++]=*it;}
    cout<<" ";
    if(v.size()>0&&v.size()!=5)
    board[i][j].color=first[rand()%i34];
    else if (v.size()==5) board[i][j].color=first[rand()%4];
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Looks like some dynamic programming problem. You might need to search for some algorithm in this field, I'm sure there is a solution. Can't get the name from top of my mind.

Comment: It is unclear from the question whether the restriction is a) no more than 2 different colours in an entire row or column, b) no more than 2 tiles of any one colour, or c) no more than 2 *adjacent* tiles of matching colour.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeatedly picking a colour and then checking it with your rules, apply the rule *first* and make an array of available colours. Then pick the array index at random. If there are no available colours: rewind, removing the previously selected colour from the previous list.

Suppose you have 3 colours. Instead of repeatedly using

```
board[i][j].color = rand() % 3;
```

until the colour fits the rules, you can build an array of colours that do fit the rules, such as

```
int avail_color[3];
int num_avail;
```

You then pick the colour like this

```
board[i][j].color = avail_color[ rand() % num_avail ];
```

Similar to [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: Sir, In my present scheme of things populating avail_color[] would need the same computation as running a loop up and back. And number of elements in avail_color will be variable which is not allowed in C,C++

Comment: You will not avoid implementing your rule. With my method, you don't need to repeatedly call `rand()` until you find a colour that fits, possibly checking the same colour with the rule several times. And the array is not variable length, it is length `[3]`. The var `num_avail` tells you how many colours are in that array - the number of elements actually used.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, you will have to implement a function that compute if a tile is in a "3 same color tile group".

Implement it and use it in your color assignment function.

Whish is:

> For every tile.
>   Choose a Random color until it doesn't make a "3 same color tile group".

Answer (score 0):

What i wanted was to implement the minus set operation where i preclude those colours from being in contention for random selection which are repeated twice to the left or below.

```
for(i=0;i<maxx;i++)
        for(j=0;j<maxy;j++)
        {exzero=exone=extwo=exthree=0;
            board[i][j].x0=x0+i*dx+1;
            board[i][j].x1=x0+(i+1)*dx-1;
            board[i][j].y0=y0+j*dy+1;
            board[i][j].y1=y0+(j+1)*dy-1;
            if((i-1)>=0&&board[i-1][j].color==0&&(i-2)>=0&&board[i-2][j].color==0)
                exzero=1;
            if((i-1)>=0&&board[i-1][j].color==1&&(i-2)>=0&&board[i-2][j].color==1)
                exone=1;
            if((i-1)>=0&&board[i-1][j].color==2&&(i-2)>=0&&board[i-2][j].color==2)
                extwo=1;
            if((i-1)>=0&&board[i-1][j].color==3&&(i-2)>=0&&board[i-2][j].color==3)
                            exthree=1;
            if((j-1)>=0&&board[i][j-1].color==0&&(j-2)>=0&&board[i][j-2].color==0)
                exzero=1;
            if((j-1)>=0&&board[i][j-1].color==1&&(j-2)>=0&&board[i][j-2].color==1)
                exone=1;
            if((j-1)>=0&&board[i][j-1].color==2&&(j-2)>=0&&board[i][j-2].color==2)
                extwo=1;
            if((j-1)>=0&&board[i][j-1].color==3&&(j-2)>=0&&board[i][j-2].color==3)
                            exthree=1;
            compositebin=exzero|exone<<1|extwo<<2|exthree<<3;
        //  cout<<compositebin<<" ";
            switch(compositebin)
            {
            case 0:board[i][j].color=rand()%4;break;
            case 1:board[i][j].color=rand()%2?1:2;break;
            case 2:board[i][j].color=rand()%2?0:2;break;
            case 3:board[i][j].color=2;break;
            case 4:board[i][j].color=rand()%2?1:0;break;
            case 5:board[i][j].color=1;break;
            case 6:board[i][j].color=0;break;
            case 7:break;
            case 8:board[i][j].color=rand()%2?rand()%2?0:1:2;break;
            case 9:board[i][j].color=rand()%2?1:2;break;
            case 10:board[i][j].color=rand()%2?0:2;break;
            case 11:board[i][j].color=2;break;
            case 12:board[i][j].color=rand()%2?1:0;break;
            case 13:board[i][j].color=1;break;
            case 14:board[i][j].color=0;break;
            case 15:break;
            }

        }
```

This piece of code using flags exclude zero,exclude one, exclude two and exclude three to exclude the four colours does a tidy job. I form a composite binary number and switch according to its value to randomly select from a subset of {0,1,2,3}.